# Can MongoDB pipeline query projection(aggregation) be case insensitive?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to execute MongoDB pipeline query with projection which ignores casing.

I have sample Test DB, Collection and documents/records:

```
use test;
db.createCollection('movie');
db.movie.insert({"name" : "A", "actors": ['Actor1', 'Actor2'], 'ReleaseYear':2021});
db.movie.insert({"name" : "B", "actors": ['Actor3', 'Actor4'], 'releaseYear':2022});
db.movie.insert({"name" : "C", "actors": ['Actor5', 'Actor6'], 'releaseyear':2023});
```

In the above, the documents have a property of `ReleaseYear` but with different casing.

Using the query below we get only the 'A' movie document:

```
db.movie.aggregate([{"$project":{"Lead Role" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$actors", 0 ] }, "Release Year":"$ReleaseYear"}}]).pretty();
```

Using this we get only the 'B' movie document:

```
db.movie.aggregate([{"$project":{"Lead Role" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$actors", 0 ] }, "Release Year":"$releaseYear"}}]).pretty();
```

How can I get all relevant records ignoring the casing of the 'ReleaseYear' property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names are case-sensitive. Transfomration is not trivial, so better take care to use proper field names. Use this one:

```
db.movie.aggregate([
   { $set: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: "$data",
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: {
                        $regexMatch: {
                           input: "$$this.k",
                           regex: "releaseYear",
                           options: "i"
                        }
                     },
                     then: { k: "releaseYear", v: "$$this.v" },
                     else: "$$this"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
   {
      $project: {
         "Lead Role": { $arrayElemAt: ["$actors", 0] },
         "Release Year": "$data.releaseYear"
      }
   }
]);
```